# How can i find specific Image Control and set its ImageUrl property (ASP.net - vb)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have 5 Images in the Page
Each has unique id

img1, img2, img3, img4, img5

i have a textbox in which i type img1 then click find me button
that find me button picks the textbox1 text which is img1 and transfer 
it to a string variable img_check

i can access img1.ImageUrl = "default.jpg"
but i want to access it using the value in the string variable
for example img_check.ImageUrl

I am not able to find any way to access controls dynamically.

Because i wish to set the property of multiple controls 
for example Imge  control ImageUrl property and Textbox Text property.

Kindly help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx that is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: i have tried this but i am not getting the property of the ImageURL if i try following

Dim img As Control = FindControl("img1")
when i type

img.

i dont get any ImageUrl property

Comment: You must CType return value in type of your control as FindControl is a generic function, which return a `System.Web.UI.Control`.

Comment: And if that doesn't help then please post your code.

Comment: I am getting the same result even if i type 

Dim img As System.Web.UI.Control = FindControl("img1")

Comment: Die you read Simon's comment about having to CType the return value? You have to cast the control to an Image-object in order to assign the ImageUrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mboldt says :

```
Dim myImg As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image = CType(FindControl(mytextbox.Text), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)
myImg.ImageUrl = "~/ImageFolder/default.jpg"
```

Inspired by: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class temp
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim img_chk As String
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        img_chk = TextBox1.Text

        Dim myImg As Image = CType(FindControl(img_chk), Image)
        myImg.ImageUrl = "~/ImageFolder/default.jpg"

    End Sub

End Class

Comment: if i get rid of the imports then it works fine but if i use import System.Drawing.Imaging it stops wokring

Comment: It is not System.Drawing.Image you need, it's  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`. Sorry my bad, I wasn't clear enough. I edited my answer.

Comment: actually i am re-sizing the uploaded image, after that determining where to place the image. I have used system.drawing.image for that

Comment: There is now way to show this image to user like you seems to look for. To achieve this, you should save physically your image in you web app and then, refers to it using ` System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` by setting ImageUrl to where you saved your image. This is the way to do it.

Comment: can i have your email so i can send you the actual file, so that you can have an idea what i am talking about

Comment: SO is not made to share email my friend, sorry. Edit your initial post so other may help you out and anyone else who have same issue as you have, may take advantage and resolve their issues also. There is no big deal with your problem. Just show us more code and we'll help you with it.